# how to create a twig template header in all page in SULU?

Tags: header, twig, sulu

I want to create an header with can be display or not in all page thanks to a checkbox in back office. I create the twig component and the link can be change in BO. I don't know how to applie with change to all the page in SULU.

Answer (score 0):

The feature what you are searching for is called Snippet Areas / Default Snippets in sulu. You can create a snippet.xml and in the webspace select that snippet and use the `sulu_snippet_load_by_area` twig extension to load that content.

See for more information in the documentation: https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/cookbook/default-snippets.html